# Replacement Rule for "flattening" list whilst adding attributes

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I am struggling with replacement rules for what I am trying to and would appreciate any assistance.

In short, given an arbitrarily nested list (`nl`), I would like to create a list of lists `ll`, where each element (a list in the new list `ll`) contains some information about the structure about its corresponding nesting in `nl`.

For example:

```
ll = {1, 1, {2, 2, {3, {4}, 3}, 2}}
(* replacement rule *)
nl = { 
   (* el, index if flattened, level *)
   {1, 1, 1},
   {1, 2, 1},
   {2, 3, 2},
   {2, 4, 2},
   {3, 5, 3},
   {4, 6, 4},
   {3, 7, 3},
   {2, 8, 2}
}
```

If I try something like:

```
LeveledList[data___][request_] := Association[data][request]
LeveledList[list_List, level_Integer: 0] := 
 LeveledList[
  "data" -> 
   Replace[list, x_List :> LeveledList[x, level + 1], {1, Infinity}], 
  "level" -> level + 1]
```

Then `ll` becomes:

```
LeveledList[
 "data" -> {1, 1, 
   LeveledList[
    "data" -> {2, 2, 
      LeveledList[
       "data" -> 
        LeveledList[
         "data" -> {3, 
           LeveledList[
            "data" -> 
             LeveledList[
              "data" -> 
               LeveledList[
                "data" -> LeveledList["data" -> {4}, "level" -> 4], 
                "level" -> 3], "level" -> 3], "level" -> 2], 3}, 
         "level" -> 3], "level" -> 2], 2}, "level" -> 2]}, 
 "level" -> 1]
```

Which keeps the nesting but adds level information.

This attempt gets the right data in this tuple structure, but it also converts keeps the nesting, which I need to drop...

```
ClearAll[TupledLeveledList];
TupledLeveledList[leveled_LeveledList] :=
 Replace[
  leveled,
  ll_LeveledList :> Table[
    {
     ll["data"][[i]],
     ll["level"],
     i
     }
    , {i, Length[ll["data"]]}],
  All
  ]
```

Although I can always convert back to normal via

```
ToNormal[l_LeveledList]:=Replace[l, ll_LeveledList:>ll["data"],All]
```

Comment: are the roles of `nl` and `ll` switched in your second paragraph?

Comment: @kglr not quite sure what you mean, but I just need to know some level specific data in a flattened form e.g. the non-list element, the flattened-index of said element, the level in which it was found and if it was the last element at that level (for a given sub-nesting). e.g. `{1,{2,2},{2,2}}` both of each last two would be the last of its given level (positions [[2,-1]] and [[3,-1]] respectively)

Comment: I meant, given the example that follows it , shouldn't second paragraph  the read "given a nested list (`ll`)..."? Or, Given your second paragraph, should the example read `nl = {1,1, {2,2...}; ll={{1,1,1}...}`?

Comment: @kglr I can se how that can be confusing as both `nl` (nestedList) and `ll` (listOfLists) are actually nested lists. The difference being in that `ll` is structured (a tuple) and `nl` being unstructured (uneven nesting or arbitrary depth)

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: @rhermans got a bit caught up for the past few days. Also was working with both answers provided here to try them in my specific use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

To address the issue of indicating whether an element is the last at its depth:

```
extractListStructure[ll_, atomQ_: Not@*ListQ] :=
  
  Block[{i = 1, prev = None},
   Reap[
     MapIndexed[
      Function[
       If[atomQ@#,
        If[ListQ@prev, 
         prev[[4]] = False;
         Sow@prev
         ];
        prev = {#, i++, Length@#2, None},
        If[ListQ@prev,
         prev[[4]] = True;
         Sow@prev;
         prev = None
         ]
        ];
       #
       ],
      ll,
      All
      ]
     ][[2, 1]]
   ];

extractListStructure@{1, 1, {2, 2, {3, {4}, 3}, 2}}

{
 {1, 1, 1, False},
 {1, 2, 1, False},
 {2, 3, 2, False},
 {2, 4, 2, False},
 {3, 5, 3, False},
 {4, 6, 4, True},
 {3, 7, 3, True},
 {2, 8, 2, True}
 }
```

I also made this more flexible in format. It takes an `atomQ` which tells it whether to treat the thing as an element or something to loop over:

```
extractListStructure[
 list[1, 1, {2, 2, {3, {4}, 3}, 2}],
  MatchQ@Except[_list | _List]
 ]

{{1, 1, 1, False}, {1, 2, 1, False}, {2, 3, 2, False}, {2, 4, 2, 
  False}, {3, 5, 3, False}, {4, 6, 4, True}, {3, 7, 3, True}, {2, 8, 
  2, True}}
```

---

Not gonna lie, I didn't read your question carefully, so if I'm way off base tell me to take a hike.

But if you just want to get `nl` you can do it like so:

```
extractListStructure[ll_] :=
  Module[{i = 1},
   Reap[
     MapIndexed[
      If[! ListQ@#,
        Sow[{#, i++, Length@#2}]
        ] &,
      ll,
      All
      ]
     ][[2, 1]]
   ];

extractListStructure@{1, 1, {2, 2, {3, {4}, 3}, 2}}

{
 {1, 1, 1},
 {1, 2, 1},
 {2, 3, 2},
 {2, 4, 2},
 {3, 5, 3},
 {4, 6, 4},
 {3, 7, 3},
 {2, 8, 2}
 }
```

Comment: going to look through it with some test examples, but looks like promising magic :)

Comment: I am accepting as answer as you did answer the question asked, but I would like to ask a follow up if you have the time. I do not yet completely understand you code (reading docs now), so it is unclear to me how to modify it. How could I add a boolean flag in as a 4th item in the tuple as to if the element is the last element in its level. e.g. `... {4}, 3},2}...` would be true the rest would be false

Comment: @SumNeuron wait a bit to accept. Someone might come through with something better. There is no direct way to get that unfortunately as it is. `Map[..., All]` is processes element-wise so there are no "look-aheads". But I can rewrite this to only `Sow` *after* the element has been passed, effectively providing a look-ahead. I'll rewrite things a bit.

Comment: that is the issue I am facing. I have several inelegant solutions for this with some recursive tables, but then I tried doing it symbolically - which was harder actually.. (at least for me). Just to clarify the last element in a level is specific to each instance of that level e.g. in `{a, {b,c},{d,e}}` both `c` and `e` are last elements in level 2, and there doesnt happen to be one for level 1.

Comment: @SumNeuron see the edit, hopefully that does what you wat

Comment: yeah! it is pretty great. Thank you again for all your help, time and expertise (not just for this question, but across several others). Can MappedIndex also provide the local index within the level? Or is that when I have to switch back to recursion? because when I recurse, I struggle with unnesting the lists :/

Comment: @SumNeuron that'll be the last argument in `#2`. It gives the full index structure as a list. So `#2[[-1]]` is where in the deepest enclosing list you are.

Comment: thanks again for all the assistance. I have updated this for my specific use case with all your help :D. I have another follow up in regards to the MatchQ for treating things as an element. E.g. if I want to wrap a list myWrappedList[{1,2,3}] and have this treat it as an element, using MatchQ@_myWrappedList, then the boolean is always true, I am looking into it, but maybe you have an idea why?

Comment: @SumNeuron that’s an edge case I didn’t think to handle. The “look-ahead” it performs is that the new element is a List. I should have had it being that the Depth (Length@#2) has decreased... I’ll try to remember to fix that up when I have time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79870/discussion-between-sumneuron-and-b3m2a1).

Answer (score 2):

```
MapThread[Append,
  {MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1]]}&, Flatten @ ll], 
  Flatten @ MapIndexed[Length@#2&, ll, {-1}] }]
```

or

```
Join[MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1]]} &, Flatten@ll], 
   List /@ Flatten @ MapIndexed[Length@#2 &, ll, {-1}], 2]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 4, 2}, {3, 5, 3}, {4, 6, 
>     4}, {3, 7, 3}, {2, 8, 2}}

Also

```
Block[{g}, Flatten[Module[{i = 1}, 
   MapIndexed[g[#, i++, Length@#2] &, ll, {-1}]]] /. g -> List]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 4, 2}, {3, 5, 3}, {4, 6,  4}, {3, 7, 3}, {2, 8, 2}}

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Block[{g}, Module[{gb,
       l1 = Flatten[Module[{i = 1}, MapIndexed[g[#, i++, Length@#2, #2] &, #, {-1}]]]},
     gb = GatherBy[l1, Length[#[[-1]]] &];
     gb[[All, -1, -1]] = True;
     gb[[All, ;; -2, -1]] = False;
     SortBy[Flatten @ gb, #[[2]] &]] /. g -> List] &;

f @ ll
```

> {{1, 1, 1, False}, {1, 2, 1, True}, {2, 3, 2, False}, {2, 4, 2, 
>         False}, {3, 5, 3, False}, {4, 6, 4, True}, {3, 7, 3, True}, {2, 8, 
>         2, True}}

Comment: may I ask for your help again? I am struggling, in one pass, to - instead of whether or not an element is at its level instance - figure out at the lowest level an element is last at, e.g. `{1,{{{2,3}},4},5}`3 is last at level 4, but it's container is last at level 3 as wel...

Comment: @SumNeuron, I will post an update if i can figure out a solution.

Comment: you are too kind. I can do this with several passes of linear functions, but nothing that does it in one sweep

Comment: @SumNeuron, what would be the desired output for the example `{1,{{{2,3}},4},5}`?

Comment: (for just this parameter) so `[[;;, 4]]` {0, 0, 3, 1, 1}. If it were `{{{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}}}` then `{0,2,0,1}`. I don't know if I am explaining it right. The issue, is that I am trying to capture a relationship between two elements with absolute indicies `i, j s.t. j=i+1`. and if element at index `i` is last in a list, what effects element at index `j` is the entire nesting which proceeds it. Often this is reflected in the fact that both reside in the same level, but with more complex nesting, if the i is the last at it's nesting (and putatively other nesting), j cares about the lowest

Comment: @SumNeuron, `{0, 0, 3, 1, 1}` or  `{0, 0, 4,2, 1}`?

Comment: if I use `...` to make the closure more apparent (to myself) `{1, {..., 4}, 5}` the elements inside the list `{..., 4}` are at level 2, but the list itself is level 1. So I think I internally skipped a beat and made this `lvl-1` adjustment (which I do for my application). e.g. if I changed it to `{1,{{{2,3}, 6},4},5}`, the value for `3` would not change, as while `3` is at level 4, its list container is at level 3, 6 would be at level 2 and 4 remains at level 1. ugh this is a headache :D